# Re-deploy node-red dashboard from the UI

Tags: dashboard, node-red

I have a dashboard made out of different template-, chart, text-input and text-output nodes. Is it possible to update, clear or re-deploy the whole dashboard with its many tabs at once with a button in the UI?
many thanks in advance.

Comment: consider adding more information in your question, e.g. your code to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to redeploy the Dashboard UI.

If you make a change to the flow that creates the dashboard, then the dashboard will automatically update when you deploy the flow.